# How to disable on-the-fly diagnostics in eglot?

Tags: lsp, eglot

How can I disable any sort of on-the-fly diagnostics in eglot?

This does not seem to be possible by customizing `eglot-ignored-server-capabilites`. Disabling `flymake-mode` using a `major-mode-hook` also does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling `flymake-mode` on `eglot-managed-mode-hook` should work.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Could you post the actual code to make this a complete answer?

Answer (score 4):

I ended with the same situation, Where I wanted to use flymake directly with eslit wihout eglot. This code worked for me

```
  (add-hook 'eglot-managed-mode-hook (lambda ()
                   (remove-hook 'flymake-diagnostic-functions 'eglot-flymake-backend)
                   (flymake-eslint-enable)))
```